# Two tables single registraton form

Tags: php

Now, How can I store two different value in a single table through one submit button. For example, In my registration form, i have 2 radio buttons in which Beginner and Professional are 2 options.

Code:

```
<form method="post" action="">      
 <input name="realname" value="" type="text">
 <input name="form_sign_up_ok" value="74285hda28" type="hidden">
 <input name="email" value="" type="text">
 <input name="password" type="password">
 <span>
  <input name="recmnd_frnd_option" value="yes" type="radio"> Yes
 </span> 
 <span>
  <input name="recmnd_frnd_option" value="no" checked="checked" type="radio"> No
 </span>
 <input name="recmnd_frnd_email" value="" type="text">
 <input value="Done" name="submit_form" type="submit">
 <input name="site_country" value="UK" type="hidden">               
</form>
```

Now, when i click on yes, and enter email id..Then after  submitting form  i want the values to be stored in different table.

Comment: What are you tried so far? Where is your code?

Comment: Add some code in your question.

Comment: Whats the issue then, do some customization!

Comment: This question is tagged as php and it is about php, all we can see is HTML code

Comment: @Jal Panchal , You mean you want to select either of table on radio button?

Answer (score 0):

You can store values from a form into multiple table by using transactions or just multiple `INSERT` statements.

using `Transactions`

```
try {
//begin a transaction
$db->beginTransaction();


$db->query("INSERT INTO users (username, email)VALUES('John', 'email@email.com')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO users1 (username, email)VALUES('Peter', 'email@email.com')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO users2 (username, email)VALUES('Given', 'email@email.com')");

$db->commit();
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
//exception thrown
  $db->rollback();
}
```

using multiple `INSERT` statement

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO users (username, email)VALUES('John', 'email@email.com')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO users1 (username, email)VALUES('Peter', 'email@email.com')");
$db->query("INSERT INTO users2 (username, email)VALUES('Given', 'email@email.com')");
```